# How to generate Kotlin Data Classes for FHIR resource types using JSON Schema or Template

Tags: json, kotlin, hl7-fhir

Im attempting to develop a mobile client that can accept FHIR bulk export Patient and Clinical Impression data sets in json format.

I want to employ Kotlin serialisation and need to generate matching data classes to consume the bulk data.

The FHIR web site provides a full json schema and json templates for both Patient and clinical impression messages however i cannot find a suitable generator to produce the required family of kotlin data classes to support serialisation/deserialisation.

How can I generate the required data classes?

Comment: You might be better off doing generation against the StructureDefinition files, as they're more complete and are the 'official' definitions of the structure.

Comment: @LloydMcKenzie thanks, where can i obtain the v4.0.1 StructureDefinition files and is the existing tools to generate kotlin from them?

Comment: no, but there is HAPI-fhir, and an immense amount of work has gone into the generated classes. You can use them from kotlin. And there's some features of the format that makes serialising straight from kotlin using inbuilt serialisation tricky. It's possible, but do you really need to do that?

Comment: And you get the files Lloyd is referring to from http://hl7.org/fhir/r4/downloads.html

Comment: There's a definitions.json.zip and definitions.xml.zip file in the core spec and each IG.  I don't know if there are Kotlin conversion tools.  There was a bit of Kotlin discussion here: https://chat.fhir.org/#narrow/stream/179166-implementers/topic/Kotlin.20Multiplatform

Comment: @GrahameGrieve the HAPI-fhir GitHub link results in HTTP 404, where have the hapi data model classes for java been relocated to?

Comment: https://github.com/hapifhir/org.hl7.fhir.core